# Non-Admin access to SQL Server Configuration Manager

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way that access can be granted for a non-admin user for SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 0):

There is but it would be a bit painful to implement and might be granting more access than you think.

It will depend on what level of access you want (read only, or ability to manage services). This is mostly a guess for SSCM but in Window Server 2003 you used to use "SUBINACL" command line to grant access. I believe this is still availble in higher OS but you would need to check.

Outside of that just specific to SSCM, this uses WMI calls in the background so at most you are going to need permissions to execute WMI calls. Understand that this is not just specific to SSCM so granting access to this may give more permissions that is needed.

I am also aware that the old "sc" command was used to grant permissions to services so that might also be used as well. This was required when WMI calls did not work properly and services did not show up in SSCM like they should.

Comment: Sean, Thank you for answering my question. I will pass it on to our administrator and see what we can do.